# Memory leak when storing Mat instance clones to an array

Tags: javascript, opencv, mat

I am reading a video and storing the Mat instance clones of each frame to an array so I could play it back on demand and also analyze the frames. Once i process the video and store the frames in the array - the memory snapshot increases from 150Mb to 1000Mb within the JSArrayBufferData.

I have to mention that i'm using Vue.js frontend framework to store the array within vue's data observable that's an array.

I've tried deleting and setting each frame to zero just to see if that would release the memory, but nothing seems to work.

Maybe it also has something to do due to me using recursive function call 
https://jsfiddle.net/j93tmr6f/

```
    new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   videoFrames: [],
   videoFile: null,
   frame: null,
   videoCap: null,
  },
  methods: {
  videoEnded() {
  console.log('ended')
     this.streaming = false
      // show first frame from small frames array
      this.playFrame(this.videoFrames[11])
    },
    videoChanged: function(fieldName, file){
        this.videoFile = URL.createObjectURL(file[0])
      this.$refs.videoRef.src = this.videoFile
      this.loadFrames()
    },
    loadFrames() {
      this.isProcessing = true
            this.streaming = true
      this.videoFrames = []
      const videoRef = this.$refs.videoRef
      const [height, width] = [720, 1280]
      this.$refs.canvasOutput.width = width / 2
      this.$refs.canvasOutput.height = height / 2
      videoRef.width = width
      videoRef.height = height

      this.videoCap = new cv.VideoCapture(videoRef)
      videoRef.play()

      setTimeout(this.scanFrames, 0)

  },
  scanFrames() {
    if (!this.streaming) return 
      try {
        const [height, width] = [720, 1280]

        this.frame = new cv.Mat(height, width, cv.CV_8UC4)
        let begin = Date.now()
        this.videoCap.read(this.frame)
        this.videoFrames.push(this.frame.clone())
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', this.frame)
        // remove the processed frame from memory.
        this.frame.delete()

        // schedule the next one.
        let delay = 1000 / this.FPS - (Date.now() - begin)
        setTimeout(this.scanFrames, delay)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
    }
})
```

more or less this is the structure of the code. It doesn't run on fiddle due to memory errors.

I would like to release the memory from chrome, because every time I analize video now, it could go up to 9GB in memory footprint. As you can imagine that's not the desired outcome.

Comment: _"...due to me using recursive function call"_ - There's no recursion in your code example.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Andreas. I meant that I am calling the same "this.scanFrames" method with a setTimeout within same function.